# Macros to isolate lat and long values and format for JS

Tags: macros, notepad++

Im trying to record a macro in notepad++ on a city dataset, trying to grab just the lat and longs for use in js.

For example, I am trying to turn a line like this:

'Nice',43.7034,7.2663,'France',1006402

into this:  new google.maps.LatLng(43.7034, 7.2663),

any idea on how i could do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a macro, if all the lines follow the same pattern you can do it with a regular expression plus replace https://regex101.com/r/MmUZzU/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every line containing latitude and longitude values would have the same format, you could try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^'.*?',(\d+(?:\.\d+)?),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?),'.*?',\d+$
Replace: new google.maps.LatLng\($1, $2\),
```

### Demo

Comment: beat me to it: https://regex101.com/r/MmUZzU/1

Comment: @river Sorry...on NPP you need to escape the parentheses in the replacement with backslash.